# Update rows when condition is met in other row with same value in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to find all the rows that contain "ungraded" for "data" with "type" set to "status". If there is another row with the same "id" but contains "end" for "type" and "legacy" for "data" I need to set "ungraded" to "graded" for the row found.

```
id | type   | data
31 | end    | legacy
31 | status | ungraded
31 | other  | something
56 | start  | legacy
56 | status | ungraded
56 | foo    | bar
```

In the case above id "31" "ungraded" would be set to "graded" as the other row with the same id has "end" as "type" but id "56" would stay "ungraded" as "type" is set to "start".

I am OK with standard MySQL stuff (e.g. joins, subqueries etc) but I have no idea how to even start on this one, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `exists` operator

```
UPDATE mytable t
SET    data = 'graded'
WHERE  t.type = 'status' AND
       t.data = 'ungraded' AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   mytable s
               WHERE  t.id = s.id AND
                      s.type = 'end' AND
                      s.data = 'legacy');
```

Comment: Thanks so much - It's one of those clean answers when you ask yourself "Why didn't I get the idea" ... ;-)

Comment: I just ran this and it does not work, I understand too why it does not.
In its current incarnation MYSQL does not allow you to query tables that are currently updated (vice versa) you get the error "You can't specify target table 'xxx' for update in FROM clause"  ... this is what I got.